# Showing $f(kx,ky)\geq f(x,y)$

Tags: combinations, factorial, monotone-functions

We have a function $$f(x,y)={y\choose x}$$ for $1<x<y$. We are trying to show that for a positive integer $k$, $f(kx,ky)\geq f(x,y)$.

So what I did so far was to write
$$\frac{ky(ky-1)\cdots(ky-kx+1)(ky-kx)!}{(ky-kx)!(kx)!} \geq \frac{y(y-1)\cdots(y-x+1)(y-x)!}{(y-x)!x!}$$
So we get
$$\frac{ky(ky-1)\cdots(ky-kx+1)}{(kx)!} \geq \frac{y(y-1)\cdots(y-x+1)}{x!}$$
Then I got stuck because every term on the numerator of the left hand side is greater than or equal to that of its right hand side but same goes for the denominator!

Could you anyone please give me a hint on what to do next? Is this even the right direction?

Comment: Your statement `...every term on the numerator of the left hand side is greater than ... but the same goes for the denominator!` is a misread of the equation (which is itself correct). Note that there are more terms on the left hand side than the right. As a product of fractions, the left "covers" the right. Every term on the right can be found on the left, while the left has many more terms that are greater than one (to be multiplied).

Comment: There's also a very simple combinatorial proof that is purely verbal, among several ways to prove this. What type of proof would you like to see as an answer?

Comment: you can look at the pascal triangle and observe $f(kx,ky)\geq f(x, ky)\geq f(x,y.)$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I studied the detailed proof you provided below. Could you please also tell me about the verbal combinatorial proof as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a dummy index $0 \leq j \leq x-1$ to express the right hand side as
$$\begin{align}
\binom{y}x &=\frac{y (y-1)(y-2) \cdots (y-x+2)(y-x+1)}{ x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots 2\cdot1} \\
&= \prod_{j=0}^{x-1} \frac{y-j}{x-j} \\
&=\frac{y-0}{x-0}\frac{y-1}{x-1}\frac{y-2}{x-2}\cdots\frac{y-j}{x-j}\cdots\frac{y-(x-2)}{x-(x-2)} \cdot \frac{y-(x-1)}{x-(x-1)}
\end{align}$$

Similarly examine the left hand side, but only pay attention to terms at every $k$ multiples.

$$\begin{align}
\binom{ky}{kx} &=\frac{ \mathbf{ky} (ky-1)(ky-2) \cdots \mathbf{(ky-k)} \cdots \mathbf{(ky-2k)} \cdots (ky-kx+2)(ky-kx+1)}{ \mathbf{kx}(kx-1)(kx-2) \cdots \mathbf{(kx-k)} \cdots \mathbf{(kx-2k)} \cdots 2\cdot1} \\
&=\mathbf{\frac{ky \! - \! 0}{kx \! - \! 0}} \cdot \frac{ky \! - \! 1}{kx \! - \! 1} \cdot \frac{ky \! - \! 2}{kx \! - \! 2} \cdots \frac{ky \! - \! k \! + \! 1}{kx \! - \! k \! + \! 1} \cdot \mathbf{\frac{ky \! - \! k}{kx \! - \! k}} \cdot \frac{ky \! - \! k \! - \! 1}{kx \! - \! k \! - \! 1}  \cdots \\
& \quad \cdots \frac{ky \! - \! 2k \! + \! 1}{kx \! - \! 2k \! + \! 1} \cdot \mathbf{\frac{ky \! - \! 2k}{kx \! - \! 2k}} \cdot \frac{ky \! - \! 2k \! - \! 1}{kx \! - \! 2k \! - \! 1} \cdots \frac{ky \! - \! jk \! + \! 1}{kx \! - \! jk \! + \! 1} \cdot \mathbf{\frac{ky \! - \! jk}{kx \! - \! jk}} \cdot \frac{ky \! - \! jk \! - \! 1}{kx \! - \! jk \! - \! 1} \cdots \\
&\qquad\qquad \small\text{(note that $j$ runs from $0$ to $x-1$)} \vphantom{\frac12}\\
& \quad\cdots \frac{ky-(x-1)k+1}{kx-(x-1)k+1} \cdot \mathbf{\frac{ky-(x-1)k}{kx-(x-1)k}} \cdot \frac{ky-(x-1)k-1}{kx-(x-1)k-1} \cdots \\
& \quad \cdots \frac{ky- kx + 2 }{kx - (kx-2)} \cdot \frac{ky- kx + 1}{kx - (kx-1)}
\end{align}$$
At each $j$, the term highlighted in boldface matches that on the right hand side (the left "covers" the right).
$$\frac{ky}{kx}=\frac{y}x~,\quad \frac{ky-k}{kx-k}=\frac{y-1}{x-1}~,\quad \frac{ky-2k}{kx-2k}=\frac{y-2}{x-2}~\ldots \\
\ldots,~\frac{ky -jk}{kx-jk}=\frac{y-j}{x-j}~,\ldots,~\frac{ky -(x-1)k}{kx-(x-1)k}=\frac{y-(x-1)}{x-(x-1)} $$
At the same time, since $y > x$, all the other (non-bold) terms on the left hand side are strictly greater than one: $(ky - \Delta)/(kx - \Delta) > 1$. Consequently, we have
$$\begin{align}
& \mathbf{\frac{ky-0}{kx-0}} \cdot \frac{ky-1}{kx-1} \cdot \frac{ky-2}{kx-2} \cdots \frac{ky-k+1}{kx-k+1} & &> \mathbf{\frac{ky-0}{kx-0}} = \frac{y}x \\
&\mathbf{\frac{ky-k}{kx-k}} \cdot \frac{ky-k-1}{kx-k-1}  \cdots \frac{ky-2k+1}{kx-2k+1} & & > \mathbf{\frac{ky-k}{kx-k}} = \frac{y-1}{x-1} \\ 
& \mathbf{\frac{ky-2k}{kx-2k}} \cdot \frac{ky-2k-1}{kx-2k-1} \cdots & &> \mathbf{\frac{ky-2k}{kx-2k}} = \frac{y-2}{x-2}  \\
&\qquad \vdots & &\qquad \vdots \\
&\mathbf{\frac{ky-jk}{kx-jk}} \cdot \frac{ky-jk-1}{kx-jk-1} \cdots & &> \mathbf{\frac{ky-jk}{kx-jk}} = \frac{y-j}{x-j}  \\
&\qquad \vdots & &\qquad \vdots  \\
&\mathbf{\frac{ky-(x-1)k}{kx-(x-1)k}} \cdot \frac{ky-(x-1)k-1}{kx-(x-1)k-1} \cdots & &> \mathbf{\frac{ky-(x-1)k}{kx-(x-1)k}} = \frac{y-x+1}{x-(x-1)}  
\end{align}$$
As a product of all these fractions, the left hand side $\displaystyle\binom{ky}{kx}$ is strictly larger than the right hand side $\displaystyle\binom{y}x$, where equality holds only when $k=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the well-known [absorption identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factors_of_Binomial_Coefficient) of binomial coefficients:

\begin{align*}
\binom{y}{x} = \frac{y}{x} \binom{y-1}{x-1}
\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}
\binom{ky}{kx} = \binom{ky - (k-1)x}{x} \prod_{n=x+1}^{kx} \frac{ky - kx + n}{n} \ge \binom{ky - (k-1)x}{x} 
\end{align*}
Since $y > x$ and therefore $\frac{ky - kx + n}{n} \ge \frac{n}{n} = 1$. Pascal's identity also tells us
\begin{align*}
\binom{y}{x} = \binom{y-1}{x} + \binom{y-1}{x-1} \ge \binom{y-1}{x}
\end{align*}
In other words, $f(y) = \binom{y}{x}$ is an increasing function for any fixed $x$. Therefore, to conclude
\begin{align*}
\binom{ky - (k-1)x}{x} \ge  \binom{y}{x}
\end{align*}
We need to show $ky - (k-1)x \ge y \iff y \ge x$, which is given.

Answer (score 1):

In response to [asker's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332158/showing-fkx-ky-geq-fx-y/4332277#comment9034514_4332158), here one combinatorial proof (of possibly many) that can arguably be considered as not involving calculation:

$\displaystyle\binom{ky}{kx}$ is choosing $kx$ items among $ky$ (all distinct and unordered), and we generate **some** of the results by

- partitioning the $ky$ items into $k$ groups each of size $y$. This can be done because $k$ is an integer.
- performing "choosing $x$ among $y$" within each group, having a combination of $\displaystyle \binom{y}{x}$ for each of the $k$ groups.
- This systematic way gives us $\displaystyle \binom{y}{x} \times \binom{y}{x} \times \binom{y}{x} \cdots \times \binom{y}{x} = \left[\binom{y}{x}\right]^k$, which is clearly larger than $\displaystyle \binom{y}{x}$ due to given condition $y>x>1$ such that $\displaystyle\binom{y}{x}>1$.
- Already QED, and we knew from the start that the above is merely part of the configurations in $\displaystyle\binom{ky}{kx}$. Basically, a group (of $y$ items) can choose fewer than $x$ items and other groups can choose more to compensate.

This target inequality $f(kx,\, ky) \geq f(x,y)$ is really very loose. A more interesting one would be e.g. to see if and when $f(kx,\, ky) \geq kf(x,\, y)$.

<sup>**If** it turns out the question statement contained typos, that the target inequality is in fact of a different form and not just plainly $f(x,y)$ on the right hand side, **then** please make a new post to ask about what the inequality really is stating (do not drastically change a question post). BTW it's likely there are existing posts dealing with this specific inequality of $f(kx,\, ky)$ vs. $kf(x,\, y)$.</sup>